# How would the centralization of world politics affect society?

Tags: society, politics, geopolitics

How would the centralization of world’s power affect politics and society in general? The society should be set in a period where artificial intelligence is well advanced to supplement in areas such as security- like in the use of intelligent tiny drones (millions of them) fitted with intelligent algorithms and smart cameras that can track the location of each person in the world throughout the day.

Also, the central government should be benevolent but opposed to free market capitalism and unregulated democracy. Think of it as the kind of political and economic system in China today. All countries like the US, Uganda, India etc. should be under this same rule. In short, it's like China of the future rising to control all of the world.

Comment: You have effectively answered your own question. The politics & society of your future centralized world would be similar to that of China today, but more surveillance, AI & drones. Its central government is hardly benevolent and it's having enough trouble controlling its own polity. There would be an underlying instability politically & socially in your future world.

Comment: If you just introduce it, nothing will change because nobody will accept it. You've got it backwards. Ask how society has to change in order to allow such a government. But even then it's probably too broad

Comment: "How would X affect society?" is too broad. Please narrow it down to something more concise and better defined.